# Disable comments on all posts/pages

Tags: comments

Is there a quick way to disable all comments on all posts and pages. I know that you can go into the dashboard under posts, click edit, and Do Not Allow, under comments. Is that the only way?

Answer (score 21):

The check if comments are enabled is performed by [`comments_open()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_open) function.

You can make it always return false via a filter with something like this:

```
add_filter('comments_open', '__return_false');
```

Other way would be to make comments available to only registered users (that is if you don't have open registration) in `Settings > Discussion`.

Comment: Most simple, native-wp and best solution. +1

Answer (score 2):

I have write an plugin for this job.
https://github.com/bueltge/Remove-Comments-Absolutely

WordPress has on many different points jobs and views for comments, if you will not use all this, use the plugin or customize the source for your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Bulk edit the existing pages in the dashboard Posts or Pages view as noted [here](https://wordpress.org/ideas/topic/turn-comments-onoff-for-multiple-posts-at-once):

1. Go to your All Posts page.
2. Click on the checkbox in the header.
3. Choose "Edit" under the bulk actions drop-down and then click Apply. The bulk edit area will appear.
4. In the middle of the bulk edit area will be four drop-down menus. The second one is for comments. Change it to "Do not allow".
5. Turn off pings with a similar drop-down to the right side of the bulk edit area.
6. Click the update button on the far right.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd add an answer to the above as it may not be immediately obvious to others searching for this issue.

In Settings >> Discussion you can uncheck "Allow people to post comments on new articles" in the Default article settings. 
However, note that this will only affect new posts/pages.

You can bulk edit the existing pages in the dashboard Posts or Pages view.

This may be a preferred method for some people not wanting to touch the template files, etc.

Comment: How does one bulk edit the existing pages in the dashboard Posts or Pages view? I'm not seeing an option in Posts or Pages view.

Comment: In Posts or Pages view in Dashboard, there should be a 'Bulk Actions' dropdown value. Change that to 'Edit' and then select all posts/pages or just the ones you want and then click 'Apply' and it will bring up the Bulk edit options.

Answer (score 0):

Not including the comment-form in your theme also works (that's what I usually do).